# Compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and closed. (proof verification)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Want to show: If $X$ is a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $X$ is closed and bounded.
I was able to show it was bounded but I was unsure whether my proof of showing $X$ was closed was correct.

my attempted proof: I want to show $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash X$ is open.  Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash X$.  Then since $X$ is closed it contains all its limit points.  Since $a$ is not in $X$, then $a$ is not a limit point of $X$, so there exists a open $U$ containing $a$ such that $U\backslash\{a\}  \cap X = \emptyset$, which implies $U \cap X = \emptyset$.  It follows that $a \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \backslash X$, concluding my argument.

I was wondering if this was a valid arugment, since most of the proofs I have seen in textbooks and online involve explicitly finding a $\epsilon$ such that $a$ is contained in the open ball around $a$ of radius $\epsilon$.

Much appreciated

Comment: You write "since X is closed", but isn't that what you're trying to show in the first place

Comment: Ahhh I knew I made a mistake somewhere - it seemed too easy.  Haha awesome thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Thorgott.  I used the fact that the set was closed in my argument which was what I was trying to prove.